# Why do I get NONE gradient of parameters in a loaded model in Pytorch, even after backword?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, gradient-descent, nonetype

I have a pretrained model which was saved by

```
torch.save(net, 'lenet5_mnist_model')
```

And now I am loading it back and trying to calculate fisher information matrix like this:

```
precision_matrices = {}
batch_size = 32
my_model = torch.load('lenet5_mnist_model')
my_model.eval()              #  I tried to comment this off, but still no luck
for n, p in deepcopy({n: p for n, p in my_model.named_parameters()}).items()
   p = torch.tensor(p, requires_grad = True)
   p.data.zero_()
   precision_matrices[n] = variable(p.data)
for idx in range(int(images.shape[0]/batch_size)):
   x = images[idx*batch_size : (idx+1)*batch_size]
   my_model.zero_grad()
   x = Variable(x.cuda(), requires_grad = True)
   output = my_model(x).view(1,-1)
   label = output.max(1)[1].view(-1)
   loss = F.nll_loss(F.log_softmax(output, dim=1), label)
   loss = Variable(loss, requires_grad = True)
   loss.backward()
   for n, p in my_model.named_parameters():
       precision_matrices[n].data += p.grad.data**2
```

Finally, the above code will crash at the last line, because `p.grad` is NoneType. So the error is:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'.

Could someone provide some guidance on what caused the NoneType grad for the parameters? How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loss does not backpropagate the gradients through the model, because you are creating a new loss tensor with the value of the actual loss, which is a leaf of the computational graph, meaning that there is no history to backpropagate through.

`loss.backward()` needs to be called on the output of `loss = F.nll_loss(F.log_softmax(output, dim=1), label)`.

I'm assuming that you thought you need to create a tensor with `requires_grad=True`, to be able to calculate the gradients. That is not the case. Tensors created with `requires_grad=True` are the leaves of the computational graph (they start the graph) and every operation performed on any tensor that is part of the graph is tracked such that the gradients can flow through the intermediate results to the leaves. Only tensors that need to be optimised (i.e. learnable parameters) should set `requires_grad=True` manually (the model's parameters do that automatically), everything else regarding the gradients is inferred. Neither `x` nor the `loss` are learnable parameters.

This confusion presumably arose due to the use of [`Variable`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated). It was deprecated in PyTorch 0.4.0, which was released over 2 years ago, and all of its functionality has been merged into the tensors. Please do not use `Variable`.

```py
x = images[idx*batch_size : (idx+1)*batch_size]
my_model.zero_grad()
x = x.cuda()
output = my_model(x).view(1,-1)
label = output.max(1)[1].view(-1)
loss = F.nll_loss(F.log_softmax(output, dim=1), label)
loss.backward()
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I inserted you modification and changed the last line to loss.backward(retain_graph=True), and it finally generated some values for p.grad. Do you think it is expected and my little modifcation is correct?

Comment: You shouldn't need the `retain_graph=True` for this, unless you want to call backward again on the same loss/graph, otherwise even after the graph is discarded, the `.grad` of the parameters are populated.